# advanced routes in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, action

I have this question to ask:
How can I turn this url "/ company / personal / user / 8 / profile" (where 8 is the user ID) so that the "controller" is "company" and "action" instead "profile" or "edit" Or still "photo"?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (I'm guessing that you are using cakephp 3.x):

```
Router::connect(
    '/company/personal/user/:id/profile',
    ['controller' => 'Company', 'action' => 'profile'],
    ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]
);
```

OR

```
Router::connect(
    '/company/personal/user/:id/*',
    ['controller' => 'Company'],
    ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]
);
```

OR UNDER A SCOPE

```
$routes->connect('/company/personal/user/:id/profile',
    ['controller' => 'Company', 'action' => 'profile'],
    ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id']]
);
```

*As you can see we check for the id to be an integer. If it's not integer it won't call the binded action, it will return a 404.*

Comment: thanks John. My goal is to obtain an abstract "action" (that could be profile, edit or some other), like this: /company/personal/user/8/profile, with action profile, /company/personal/user/8/edit, with action edit, and so on. the action, naturally will have a view file. All not found Controller function or view file, will return a 404

Comment: To achive this you need to add a scope and activevate scope fallbacks